# Why the picture displays on sticky header?

Tags: html, css

The picture is on header while scrolling but it should be "under it" like some other *navs* do.
[image: Website]

The picture:

```
.nav3{
float:right;
height:820px;
margin:2px; }


.waterfall {
position: relative;
left:-20%; bottom: 100%; }

<nav class="nav3">
<img class="waterfall" src="../Szablony 3/wodospad.jpg">
</nav>
```

The sticky element:

```
 <header id="header1">

#header1 {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
background-color:black;
position:sticky ;
top: 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to best understand [Ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; then post a [mre] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) The code that you have posted at the moment is incomplete and other users will need to guess at the missing parts to try and give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set z-index on navbar to something high.

```
#header1 {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
background-color:black;
position:sticky ;
top: 0;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title></title>
```

#header1 

{

height: 50px;

width: 100%;

background-color:black;

position: -webkit-sticky;

position: sticky;

top: 0;

border: 2px solid #4CAF50;

}

.nav3{

float:right;

margin:2px; 

position: relative;

z-index:-1

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).